# What really happens when I press duplicate?

Tags: odoo

I am going crazy with OpenERP duplicate, if I duplicate a User in Employee Directory it duplicates everything (every user of the system), If I duplicate a group it duplicates only some stuff, apparently it doesn't create a copy... If I copy a Menu it doesn't duplicate the submenu options.

WTF does duplicate do "under the hood"? Is duplicate the same as copy? Does it create a new reference that points to the same object? Is it a shallow or a deep copy?

I am on OpenERP 7 LTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duplicate Menu calls the OpenERP `copy` method, which by default is implemented as a shallow copy, with the exception of [`one2many`](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_02/#fields-introduction) relationships.

*Shallow copy* means that a new copy of the record is created, with all field values copied as reference as much as possible. For example if you duplicate an Employee, the Department of the duplicated employee will simply be set to the same department as the one being copied, the system will **not** create a copy of the Department.

For `one2many` relationships (which is typically the relationship that connects a parent record with its child records, like the relationship between an Invoice and its lines), the child records are also duplicated, because the original ones cannot be ripped off their original parent.
This default behavior may cause unforeseen side-effects when a `one2many` relationship connects a record to mere "related records" that are not really its children: for example a `one2many` relation could link an Employee to her timesheet entries, but those entries should definitely **not** be duplicated when the employee is duplicated.

For this reason the various object models of OpenERP can implement extra logic during the `copy` operation, and explicitly turn off the duplication for `one2many` relationships that do not contain real "children", as well as alter any copied values (like appending "(copy)" in the record name).

If you're seeing incorrect behavior when duplicating records using only standard OpenERP modules, it may be a bug that should be reported on the [official bugtracker](https://doc.openerp.com/7.0/contribute/11_bug_tracker/). And if you are using extra modules, make sure they're not adding `one2many` fields on some models without overriding the `copy` method accordingly.

PS: If you're duplicating a record in the "Employee Directory" you're actually duplicating an employee (HR Resource), not a user (User Account with login access). Those are separate concepts in OpenERP, as some employees may not need to login (no user account), and some users may not be employees (contractors or system accounts for example).

**Update**: [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/1256437) exists currently in OpenERP 7.0 that causes invalid duplication of related employees when duplicating a user, and similar duplication of subordinates when duplicating an employee. This bug is an illustration of what happens when modules fail to correctly handle the duplication of the one2many relationship they define.

Comment: Hi odony, I am actually duplicating a user, but that user has an employee associated with it, and that is where the issue occurs, it duplicates not only the user but also all employee data, and this is the part that does not make sense to me, I want to have users that are not employees... I don't see why when I copy a user I also copy all employee data and if it's a manager all it's subordinates are copied too.

Comment: Dan, that is indeed a bug in OpenERP 7.0, and your [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/1256437) is valid (assuming it's yours). The reason why this happens is explained in my answer above. The fix is trivial: the `hr` module must disable the duplication of the "Related employees" on a user, and the "Subordinates" on an employee. Thanks for opening the bug report!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is indeed mine :)
I am still new at OpenERP and Python, I am trying to locate the places that need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

As Duplicate name suggest it simply duplicate the records, in the background it calls `ORM's` copy method,

If it's duplicating only some stuff that means for the particular model the `copy` method is **overrided**, which is preventing the duplication of all fields.

If you don't want the existing functionality you can override it and change it as per your requirement by creating child module.